# Copy from Hadoop to local machine

Tags: hadoop, avro

I can ssh to our box and do a `hadoop fs -ls /theFolder`  and browse in for the files, etc.. but that's all I know too :)  My goal is to copy one of those files - they are Avro - on to my local home folder.

How can  do this? I found also a `get` command but not sure how to sue that either.

Comment: If you use MapR, you can mount your entire HDFS with NFS and then easily copy files around easily.

Comment: can you explain it a little more? I am a hadoop noob :)

Comment: MapR is a distribution of Hadoop. You can download it as a VM to play with it and mount the HDFS using NFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `hadoop fs -get /theFolder` to copy it into the current directory you are ssh'ed into on your box.

Then you can use either `scp` or my preference of `rsync` to copy the files between your box and your local system like so. Here's how I'd use `rsync` after having used the `-get`, still in the same directory:

`rsync -av ./theFolder username@yourlocalmachine:/home/username`

This will copy `theFolder` from the local fs on your box into your home folder on your machine's fs. Be sure to replace `username` with your actual username in both cases, and `yourlocalmachine` with your machine's hostname or ip address.

Answer (score 2):

Using hadoop's `get` you can copy the files from HDFS to your box's file system. Read more about using `get` [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.1/hdfs_shell.html#get).

Then, using `scp` (this is similar to doing ssh) you may copy those files to your local system. Read more about using `scp` [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/xfer/scp.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -get theFolder
```

is great just like previous answer.
For syncing with local machine, I think you can set up git. That's easy as well.